# Django query select distinct by field pairs

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the field 'submission' which has a user and a problem. How can I get an SQL search result which will give a list of only one result per user-problem pair?

Models are like this:

```
class Problem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length = 100)
    question = models.TextField('Question')

class Submission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    problem = models.ForeignKey(Problem)
    solution = models.CharKey()
    time = models.DateTimeField('Time', auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "field which has a user and a problem"? Are you talking about Django models? Post the relevant code.

Comment: Models are like this:
Problem: title, question
Submission: problem (foreignkey), user (foreignkey), content
User: auth user

Let us suppose p1, p2 two problems and u1, u2 are two users u1 has two submissions s1, s2 for p1 and one (s3) for p2 and u2 has one for p1 ( s4), two for p2 ( s5,s6)

So i want a queryset result like this: s2, s3, s4,s6

i.e. neglect the old ones with same user-problem
s2, s3,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2**:

(After reading OP's comments) I suggest adding a new model to track the latest submission. Call it `LatestSubmission`.

```
class LatestSubmission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)     
    problem = models.ForeignKey(Problem)
    submission = models.ForeignKey(Submission)
```

You can then either

1. override `Submission.save()` to create/update the entry in `LatestSubmission` every time an user posts a new solution for a Problem
2. attach a function that does the same to a suitable [signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).

such that `LatestSubmission` will contain one row per problem-user-submission combination pointing to the latest submission for the problem by each user. Once you have this in place you can fire a single query:

```
LatestSubmission.objects.all().order_by('problem')
```

**Update**:

Since the OP has posted sample code, the solution can now be changed as follows:

```
for user in User.objects.all(): # Get all users
    user.submission_set.latest('time') # Pick the latest submission based on time.
```

**Original Answer**

In the absence of any date/time based criteria for deciding which is "older" or "newer", you can use the primary key (`id`) of `Submission` to "neglect the old ones".

```
for user in User.objects.all(): # Get all users
    user.submission_set.latest('id') # Pick the latest submission by each user.
```

Comment: I added the model details to my problem.
This will give me only the query set of last submission by a user and what i want is the latest result for all the problems. I want to run a sql command on submission field and get the list of submissions ordered by submission time and will include only one result if there are more than one submissions by a same user in one problem.

Comment: @Rohan Jain: I am not sure if you can do that with _one_ SQL query given your _current_ model structure. I'd like to know if anyone else here can come up with a suitable answer.

Comment: i am doing this now by adding a is_latest boolean field for the submission.....thanx fr ur helps :)

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
distinct_users_problems = Submission.objects.all().values("user", "problem").distinct()
```

It will give you a list of dicts like this one:

```
[{'problem': 1, 'user': 1}, {'problem': 2, 'user': 1}, {'problem': 3, 'user': 1}]
```

containing all the distinct pairs.

It actually results in your usual SELECT DISTINCT SQL query.