# Django getting only the most recent object after filtering

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a questionnaire type app for Django.
When participants complete a questionnaire an AnswerSet object is created which links their user object to a list of QuestionAnswer object, one for each question that they answer.

```
class AnswerSet(models.Model):

    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    questionnaire=models.ForeignKey(Questionnaire)


class QuestionAnswer(models.Model):    

    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    answer_set = models.ForeignKey(AnswerSet)
```

The app allows people to re-answer a questionnaire, and in this case renders the form using their existing answers, and for answers that are updated, a new QuestionAnswer object is created and saved.

My question therefore is this:

In order to display the most recent answer when the participant is editing the questionnaire, I want to be able to get an AnswerSet, and then filter the QuestionAnswers so that I get a QuestionAnswer for each question, and where there are more than one QuestionAnswer for any question, I only want to see the most recent one

Comment: does any of your tables has the inserion time as a column?

Comment: Do you also want to store previous answers? If not then when you create model form for `QuestionAnswer` use existing instance so that instance will be updated when you save the form.

Comment: No I haven't got insertion time, but that could easily be added, I was thinking of using the primary key to determine the most recent answer. @Rohan yes I want to keep an audit trail of the answers.

Comment: @Ctrlspc ok, then its easy to filter by `latest(your_datetime_field)`. Its not good to rely in PK for sequencing.

Comment: @Rohan thanks but that doesn't quite do it, I have clarified what I want in the question

Comment: I suspect you may have to change your models, this question might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483307/django-query-select-distinct-by-field-pairs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion by @Rohan and this post [Django query select distinct by field pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483307/django-query-select-distinct-by-field-pairs) I have found a solution that works for me, hopefully someone else will find it useful too!
I have added a new model:

```
class LatestQuestionAnswer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    question_answer = models.ForeignKey(QuestionAnswer)
    answer_set = models.ForeignKey(AnswerSet)
    created = created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And overridden the save function on my QuestionAnswerModel so it looks like:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
        super(QuestionAnswer, self).save(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using)

        try:
            record = LatestQuestionAnswer.objects.get(question=self.question, answer_set=self.answer_set)

            if record.question_answer == self:
                return#nothing to do no point updating the record as it is already correct

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            record = LatestQuestionAnswer(question=self.question, answer_set= self.answer_set)

        record.question_answer = self
        record.save()
```

Now whenever I need to get a list of all the most recent QuestionAnswers I can do something like this:

```
most_recent_answers = [record.question_answer for record in LatestQuestionAnswer.objects.filter(answer_set=<an_answer_set>)]
```